# Fetching multiple tables on a single page by ID value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created the same topic during the day but it was not clear, I am creating it again more clearly.

I am developing an ASP.NET Core MVC project, using N-tiered architecture. I have two tables on the database side.

Table name: `TaskList`

- TaskID (primary key)
- TaskDetail

Table name: `TaskListComment`

- CommentId (primary key)
- CommentDetail
- TaskId

I am using two views `Index` and `Index2`.

On the `Index` page, the data in the `TaskList` table is listed. Then I move the details to the `Index2` page according to the `ID` value. There is no problem so far.

I also want to list the `TaskListComment` data on the `Index2` page. And I want to do this according to the `TaskId` value.

But when I want to list with the same code, it brings data according to the `CommentId` value. `CommentId` and `TaskId` values are different from each other.

`GenericRepository.cs`:

```
public T GetById(int id)
{
    using var context = new Context();
    return context.Set<T>().Find(id);
}
```

`TaskListCommentManager.cs`:

```
public TaskListComment itemGetById(int id)
{
    return _taskListCommentDal.GetById(id);
}
```

`TaskListController.cs`:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult TaskDetail(int id)
{
    taskListViewModel.TaskLists = taskListManager.itemGetById(id);
    return View(taskListViewModel);
}
```

When I use the code above for listing by `ID` value for `TaskListComment`, the `CommentId` value is based on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult TaskDetail(int id)
        {
            Context context = new Context();
            var taskListViewModel = new TaskListViewModel
            {
                TaskLists = taskListManager.itemGetById(id),
                GetTaskListComments = context.TaskListComment.Where(x => x.TaskId == id).ToList(),
            };
            return View(taskListViewModel);
        }
```

When I edited the codes as above, the problem was solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new method called GetComments (method names should start with uppercase letters) in the TaskListManager class. The GetComments method should get the list of comments using the **ID of the task**:

```
public class TaskListManager : GenericRepository<TaskList>
{
    public GetComments(int taskId)
    {
        return _context
           .TaskListComments
           .Where(c => c.TaskId == taskId)
           .ToList();
    }
}
```

Then in your TaskDetails action, you should do the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult TaskDetail(int id)
{
    var taskListViewModel = new TaskListViewModel
    {
       TaskList = _taskListManager.GetById(id),
       Comments = _taskListManager.GetComments(id)
    }

    return View(taskListViewModel);
}
```